# bootstrap modal dialog not coming up programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a page with two modal dialogs. One is activated through data attributes, and works fine. The other is activated through a `$('#myDialog').modal('show')`. When I invoke this dialog, I only get the backdrop, but don't see the dialog. Closer inspection shows that the animation that brings it in from the top of the screen doesn't seem to be firing (it's still positioned off-screen). It's not the dialog itself (I've tried switching code around to bring up the "working" dialog with JS, to no avail).

Here's the code that's supposed to bring it up (coffeescript)

> ```
>     $scope.unlinkAccount = (account) ->
>       $('#deleteAlert').modal('show')
> ```

Here's the modal html

> ```
> <div id="deleteAlert" class="modal hide fade">
>     <div class="modal-header">
>         <h2>Are you sure you want to unlink {{deleteTarget.token}}?</h2>
>     </div>
>     <div class="modal-footer">
>         <button class="btn" >Cancel</button>
>         <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="linkAccount()">Link</button>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Idears?

Comment: Does it work without the `fade` class?

Comment: no - it looks like neither hide nor fade are removed

Comment: If you just call `$('#deleteAlert').modal('show')` on its own, does it work?  Are there any other js actions that occur at the same time as the modal show?

Comment: no and no. i've tried all the variations to no avail. the only thing happening during the modal show is the snippet of code above.

Comment: Any chance there's another element on the page with ID `#deleteAlert`?

Comment: no, and - if i point this code to the modal that "works," the same thing happens. this appears to be linked to the method of invocation, not the structure of the modal itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say do not manipulate DOM in your controller code. Take the Angular way instead, which in your case would be to use [Angular-UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It has the `$dialog` service which you can leverage while keeping your controller code testable.

Comment: that's fine as a strategic direction, but doesn't solve the tactical problem.

Comment: so, i'll eat my hat here. this worked. that said - i still don't understand why, or why it should even matter.